# Timezone location AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, timezone

how can I possible get the location or the place of my timezone? I'm using angularjs and I'm using the format 'Z' but only display the numeric value. Is it possible that I can also get the specific location of each timezone? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution below: (link ref https://github.com/michaelahlers/angular-timezones/blob/master/docs/examples/filters.js)

```
(function (angular) {

  var application = angular.module('application', ['Timezones'])

  application.constant('$timezones.definitions.location', '/tz/data')

  application.controller('World', function ($scope) {
    var now = $scope.now = Date.now()

    $scope.examples = [
      { timezone : 'Pacific/Honolulu', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'America/Los_Angeles', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'America/Chicago', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'America/New_York', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'Europe/Berlin', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'Asia/Tokyo', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'Australia/Sydney', reference : now },
      { timezone : 'Etc/GMT+12', reference : now }
    ]
  })

})(angular)
```

Comment: Thank you here is my code     settingTab.controller('Ctrl2', ['$scope', function($scope) {
                    $scope.format1 = 'M/d/yy  ';
                    $scope.format = 'h';
                    $scope.format3 = 'mm';
                   $scope.format4 = 'ss';
                   $scope.format5 = 'a';
                   $scope.format2 = 'Z ';  how can i possibly add that function? the whole page is in this plunker link: http://plnkr.co/edit/uX7sAHL1XXtASzu0VH5V?p=preview Thank you so much for your help :)